# packet loss. how to resolve this?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

how to find out the packet loss? when the router is transmitting the packets of data to destination. If the  destination will not receive the ex-tact transmitted packets there will be loose of data.
           How the Source(router) will know that data is not received by the destination side. And how it will retransmit the data from the source to destination.

Comment: It depends on the protocol used. Not all protocols are designed to re-transmit lost data.

Comment: If it is WiFi 802.11  protocol. Then how it will retransmit the lost data

Answer (score 0):

Without getting to technical, network devices send packets of data with information about that data to a receiving end.  The receiving device checks to see if the data matches the information sent with it and acknowledges back to the sender.  If the data is bad, it requests it to be resent.  If for some reason the receiving end does not reply, that is a lost packet.

Comment: UDP won't request a re-transmit ... :)

Comment: Here I am using TCP protocol.